# Spring MVC: how does spring MVC decide which handler object to use?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

DispatcherServlet has 3 default handler adaptors: HttpRequestHandlerAdapter, SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter, and AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter. In some situation, DispatcherServlet could find two or more handler objects based on handler mappings. For example, the method on the handler object from AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter and the handler object from SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter. My question is which handler object DispatcherServlet invoke? Can I set priorities of these three? If so, How?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HandlerAdapters` are ordered using a `OrderComparator`, so you can set the priority via `setOrder()` method in `Ordered` interface.

Comment: What a answer buddy..+10 from me